Issue Installing Ubuntu on Lenovo ThinkPad T470
I've been trying to install Ubuntu on my Lenovo ThinkPad T470, which originally had Windows 10. I removed Windows to install just Ubuntu, but I'm facing issues with both versions 22.04.4 and 24.04.
Here's What Happens:

I create a bootable USB drive and boot from it.
Ubuntu runs fine from the USB and allows me to perform tasks.
After installing Ubuntu on my SSD and rebooting, the system doesn't boot into Ubuntu.
I remove the USB drive and press Enter as prompted, but I'm only presented with a boot menu where I can select between USB or NVMe SSD. Neither option works.

Current BIOS/UEFI Settings:

Boot Mode: Set to Legacy, but I tried UEFI as well.
Boot Order: NVMe SSD is set as the first boot device.

Attempted Fixes:

Tried changing the boot mode to UEFI, but it reverts to Legacy upon reboot.
Ran Boot-Repair, which suggested adding a /boot partition at the beginning of the disk.

Issues:

The system keeps reverting to Legacy mode.
Ubuntu won't boot from the SSD after installation.

I'm stuck on this issue and would appreciate any help or guidance on how to resolve it.

A 2017+ Lenovo T470 with Windows 10 came on a gpt partitioned disk in UEFI mode. Forget Legacy.  Now that machine may have a setting to choose the preferred boot mode (legacy or UEFI) -- ensure that also prefers UEFI over legacy.  A legacy preference here, without any legacy bootloaders will eventually boot to a properly set up UEFI, but the Ubuntu install media has both modes, so maybe that's how legacy got into the mix. Some tools may take the ISO and produce a USB that boots only one way.  Select UEFI if you must make a choice, otherwise, let the install media boot whatever mode the machine selects.
/boot holds the linux kernels and is not the EFI partition, nor the legacy bios-grub partition. Ancient machines whose firmware could only address the first part of the disk needed the kernels in that early part, hence the separate /boot early in the disk to ensure that.  Other uses are a firmware readable partition on an otherwise encrypted or LVMed or raid setup, but you didn't mention any of that. Forget setting up /boot, just leave it in your root as the boot directory.
The EFI menu (some key at power-up to allow you to select a device or OS to boot) may help you get booted, but you should be able to set things up with the machine's boot order or Ubuntu's efibootmgr to boot the way you want.
